# Evolution Install

Tags: software-installation, evolution

I'm trying to install Evolution and the Ubuntu Software manager tries to install it and just stops. Evolution gets pinned to the launch bar but won't start.

I then tried from the command line using `sudo apt-get install evolution evolution-mapi` but that fails with the following output:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-symbolic libasn1-8-heimdal
3 upgraded, 30 newly installed, 0 to remove and 481 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,877 kB/20.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 60.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libevolution amd64 3.2.3-0ubuntu5
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]

...Truncated because of the dumb link limit as I'm a new user...

Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evolution/evolution-plugins_3.2.3-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.183 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: You can use http://pastebin.com for long outputs. They are much more readable there then inside questions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried as suggested in error message?

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```